# How to Integrate Page Routing and Transitions in Next.js latest using layout.tsx and _app.tsx

Tags: next.js, next.js13, framer-motion, framer-animatepresence

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up page routing with the new `layout.tsx` feature in Next.js. I have an `_app.tsx` file that enables page transitions with Framer-Motion and `AnimatePresence`. I'm unsure about how to connect this with my `layout.tsx`

_app.tsx

```
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pageKey = router.asPath;

  return (
    <div>
      <AnimatePresence initial={false} mode="popLayout">
        <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">{pageKey}</div>
        <Component key={pageKey} {...pageProps} />
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}
```

layout.tsx

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "@/components/layout/header";
import Lines from "@/components/line/lines";
import Footer from "@/components/layout/footer";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "A website for gamers",
  description: "A website for gamers is a website for gamers.",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <main className="min-h-screen grid grid-rows-[auto,1fr,auto]">
          <Header />
          <div className="relative overflow-hidden">
            <Lines />
            {children}
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

PageTransisiton

```
import React, { forwardRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { motion, HTMLMotionProps, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

type PageTransitionProps = HTMLMotionProps<"div">;
type PageTransitionRef = React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>;

function PageTransition(
  { children, ...rest }: PageTransitionProps,
  ref: PageTransitionRef
) {
  const fromTheBottom = { y: "100%" };
  const inTheMiddle = { y: 0 };
  const toTheTop = { y: "-100%" };

  const transition = { duration: 0.6, ease: "easeInOut" };

  return (
    
      <motion.section
        className="relative flex-1 h-full flex flex-col"
        ref={ref}
        initial={fromTheBottom}
        animate={inTheMiddle}
        exit={toTheTop}
        transition={transition}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.section>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(PageTransition);
```

Page.tsx

```
"use client";

import Hero from "@/components/hero/hero";
import PageTransition from "@/components/pageTransition";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

type IndexPageProps = {};
type IndexPageRef = React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>;

function IndexPage(props: IndexPageProps, ref: IndexPageRef) {
  return (
    <PageTransition ref={ref}>
      <Hero />
    </PageTransition>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(IndexPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly.

Why are your using page transitions with Framer Motion and AnimatePresence in the first place?

Page routing in Next.js 13 remains similar to the previous versions.

In previous versions, you would define pages like this:
**In the "pages" folder you would define the pages:**

- `pages/home.tsx => //https:www.mydomain.com/home`
- `pages/about.tsx => //https:www.mydomain.com/about`

With the app router in Next.js 13, the structure is slightly different.
**You create a folder with the name of your page in the "app" folder, and within that folder, you create a `page.tsx` file.**  For example:

- `app/home/page.tsx => //https:www.mydomain.com/home`
- `app/about/page.tsx => //https:www.mydomain.com/about`

The `layout.tsx` file is **optional** and is intended for **UI components shared between routes.**

Here is the **official documentation for the file conventionsin next 13.**
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions